# Spark Streaming GroupBy Parts of a Tuple to Process

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming job that is running off of Kafka. I get messages in like this:

```
val messageStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, (String, Int, Long, String)](ssc, getKafkaBrokers(), getKafkaTopics("raw"), (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => {
  (mmd.topic, mmd.partition, mmd.offset, mmd.message)
})
```

Now as I bring data in I want to group by the topic and partition so everything with the same topic/partition I can process in one batch. What is the right function to use here

```
messageStream.foreachRDD(x => x.?
```

Is it a groupBy? and if it is a groupBy how to I group by the first 2 parts of the tuple I have in. The KafkaRDD[0] will have many messages in it so I want to group them into sets of like messages than be able to process each grouping as a chunk vs individual messages.

Edit:
So based on the below feed back so I would have something like this:

```
   messageStream.foreachRDD(x => x.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).foreach(x => {
      ?
    }))
```

Is it now in a K,V like K is (topic, partition), value is (offset, topic)? 
I need the 1st and 2nd part of the tuple because that will allow me to make an API call to get instructions on what to do with the message. What I dont want to do is individually call the API on each message because a lot of them have the same instruction set based on the topic/partition.

Edit:
Realized that it comes now as:

K:(Topic, Partition) V: CompactBuffer((Topic, Partition, Offset, Message), ()) etc.

```
messageStream.foreachRDD(x => x.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).foreach(x => {
          val topic = x._1_.1
          val partition = x._1._2
          x._2.forEach(x=> ... 
        }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to groupBy the first two parts in the tuple, you can try the following:

```
messageStream groupBy (x => (x._1, x._2))
```

Comment: Edited my response to build on what you said.

Comment: the value is still the 4-tuple.  If you only need the 3rd and 4th item you should do a `mapValues ( v => (v._3, v._4))`.

Comment: I need to 1st and 2nd part of the tuple because that will allow me to make an API call to get instructions on what to do with the message. I need the 3rd part because I have my own offset manager. What I dont want to do is individually call the API on each message because a lot of them have the same instruction set based on the topic/partition.